# Cannot locate MainActivity.java file in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am new to Android Studio and am following android's developer tutorial. I am trying to locate the MainActivity.java file in app > java > com.example.myfirstapp > MainActivity. I located the myfirstapp folder that the MainActivity.java file is supposed to be in but nothing exists there. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[Screenshot of my folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIsYo.png)

Comment: can you attach a screenshot of what you see in the project window?

Comment: @RemonShehatta just attached it

Answer (score 0):

There is no activity yet. You have to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, tutorial said to start the project as 'Empty Activity' and I accidentally created it as 'No Activity', as a result no MainActivity file was automatically created.